# How to build Qt (with QtWebEngine support) using meta-toolchain-qt5?

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, qtwebengine

I am trying to build Qt using `meta-toolchain-qt5`, but when I do this via `poky-glibc-x86_64-meta-toolchain-qt5-cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-toolchain-2.0.1.s‌​‌​h`, I don't see anything about QtWebEngine in the `sysroot` directory.

I also tried to build Qt using the following command

```
bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5
```

but it is the same result; I don't have anything regarding Qt WebEngine.

How can I build Qt with QtWebEngine support?

Comment: This question was [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327235/211627). For future reference, when the question is the same, you should update your existing post rather than creating new ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at `meta-toolchain-qt5` it inherits `populate_sdk_qt5`, which in turns adds `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target` to the SDK. Taking a closer look at `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target`, reveals that the packagegroup doesn't directly include `qtwebengine`. Thus, if  nothing else in `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target` drags in `qtwebengine` as a dependeny, `qtwebengine` won't be installed.

If you add `qtwebengine` to `RDEPENDS_${PN}` in `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target`, you'll get the relevant `qtwebengine` packages in your SDK.

Comment: Anders, I added QtWebengine-dev and qtwebengine-mkspecs.  It still return "unknown modules: qtwebengine".  This has bugs me for a while now. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much.It's work.But I receive following warning when I run qtwebengine app in embedded linux:  "Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /usr/share/qt5/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /usr/share/qt5. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /home/root. Trying fallback directory... The application MAY NOT work." Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: It works for me, with the variscite Yocto recipe. I thank you twice : for the solution, and the way to find it, that can be reuse for solving other problem that kind.